# checkbox form using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to figure out a code where if one or more checkbox is checked through a form submit, they would show their content. I'm close to doing it but the code only works in single instead of multiple checks. The content also gets stuck even though it's been unchecked after it's checked.

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $(function(){
        $('form').submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            if ($('.checkEdu').is(':checked')) 
            {   $('#education').show();
            } else if ($('.checkWork').is(':checked')){
                $('#experience').show();
            } else if ($('.checkAbout').is(':checked')){
                $('#about').show();
            }
            else {
                $('#education').hide();
                $('#experience').hide();
                $('#about').hide();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

This is the code I tried. Thanks

Comment: It would be nice to include the minimal HTML needed to reproduce your problem.

Comment: also could you elaborate on "the code only works in single instead of multiple checks" ?

Comment: Start by hiding all of them, then in seperate if's unhide accordingly.  Since you are if-else you only get 1 or the other.

Comment: `$(document).ready(function() {}` and `$(function() {}` do the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest hiding them all first and then showing the ones that are selected:

```
$('#education').hide();
$('#experience').hide();
$('#about').hide();
if ($('.checkEdu').is(':checked')){
    $('#education').show();
}
if ($('.checkWork').is(':checked')){
    $('#experience').show();
}
if ($('.checkAbout').is(':checked')){
    $('#about').show();
}
```

Comment: thank you, I actually just thought about this code and check up on this to remove it. haha!

Answer (score 1):

Try this.  Since more than one can be checked at a time they need separate if checks.

```
$(function(){
    $('form').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#education').hide();
        $('#experience').hide();
        $('#about').hide();            
        if ($('.checkEdu').is(':checked')){   
            $('#education').show();
        }
        if ($('.checkWork').is(':checked')){
            $('#experience').show();
        }
        if ($('.checkAbout').is(':checked')){
            $('#about').show();
        }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `HTML` code will be like this,

```
<form>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkEdu">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkWork">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkAbout">
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<div id="education" style="display:none;">education</div>
<div id="experience" style="display:none;">experience</div>
<div id="about" style="display:none;">about</div>
```

add following jquery code

```
$(function(){   
    $('form').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#education, #experience, #about').hide();
        $('[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(k,v){
            switch($(v).attr('class')){
                case 'checkEdu' : $('#education').show(); break;
                case 'checkWork' : $('#experience').show(); break;
                case 'checkAbout' : $('#about').show(); break;
            }
        });
    });
});
```